# How is List<WebElement> interface being implemented when I use findElements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

`List` is an interface.
`List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();`
Here, lets say we are creating a reference variable of list interface and assigning it to the `ArrayList` object which implemets `List` interface.

Lets say if we want to get the size of the list. We will use `list.size()` which will internally invoke the `size()` method of `ArrayList` object using Runtime Polymorphism.

Simply here what I mean to say is the methods of `List` is implemented in `ArrayList` class thats why we are able to use it.

Question is,

How I am able to use `size()` and how the size method is being implemented in what Class ?

```
List<WebElement> noOfRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']//tbody/tr"));
List<WebElement> noOfCol=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*/tr/th"));

int rowSize=noOfRows.size();
int colSize=noOfCol.size();
```

I hope you guys are getting my point.

When I say `List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();`
That means I am going to use `ArrayList` methods as runtime polymorphism.

But what in this case...

```
driver.get("https://money.rediff.com/gainers/bse/daily/groupa?src=gain_lose");

List<WebElement> noOfRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']//tbody/tr"));
List<WebElement> noOfCol=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*/tr/th"));


int rowSize=noOfRows.size();//How I am able to use method of a List interface
int colSize=noOfCol.size();
```

I am able to run the program and do everything but just want to clear the concept here . Seems like I am confused on a minor issue but want this confusion to be gone. Thankyou in advance

Comment: Do I get you right that you want to know the implementing class for `noOfRows` after your call to `List noOfRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[@id='leftcontainer']//tbody/tr"));`? What about calling `System.out.println( noOfRows.getClass().getName() );`?

Comment: `List<>` is a `List<>`. It doesn't matter what it contain.

Comment: the super is Collection:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: No. What I am asking is ..if I do this...List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>() . I can do list.size() because I know that size method is implemented in ArrayList class. But what about when I do List<WebElement> noOfRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']//tbody/tr")); and then noOfRows.size()....here I want to know how is size method is being implemented and where and how I able to use it. Is WebDriver implementing it or WebElement or is it being implemented using by some annoymous inner class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable in Java can have a type `List`, but it is not possible to instantiate the `List` interface, that is, to create an object of type `List` in memory. The objects in memory are of some other type that implements the `List` interface.

The object returned from `findElements` implements the interface `List`, but the actual class of that object is unknown to the compiler. You can query it at runtime, by using the `getClass` method, but that is usually not necessary because you can treat it as a `List` without having to know exactly what kind of `List` it is.

When you call `size` on the `List` returned by `findElement`, the JVM selects the correct `size` implementation to use based on the actual type of the object. So if it just happens to be an `ArrayList` then you'll get `ArrayList.size`, etc. Often the type of `List` returned from a method like this isn't one of the usual types from `java.util` but some custom implementation that is tailored to the task at hand.